# Best way to find device information on flutter app

Tags: flutter

I'm develop flutter app and I would like to show device model name on screen (see image below)

[image]

I found some flutter plugin like https://pub.dev/packages/device_info but it not show exactly model name. Any idea how do i find device model name?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the package [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus)

```
import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';

DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
print('Running on ${androidInfo.model}');  // e.g. "Moto G (4)"

IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
print('Running on ${iosInfo.utsname.machine}');  // e.g. "iPod7,1"

WebBrowserInfo webBrowserInfo = await deviceInfo.webBrowserInfo;
print('Running on ${webBrowserInfo.userAgent}');  // e.g. "Mozilla/5.0
```

Comment: This plugin is unable to provide MAC address of device for Flutter windows. How can I get mac address?

Comment: I don't think it's possible using this plugin, refer here instead: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-mac-address-of-device-in-flutter/

Comment: This plugin is for android and iOS purpose only.